# Override the schema version in a Realm database

Tags: java, realm

Is there a way using RealmBrowser or in code to override the version of a Realm database if I found mine in a complicated state because of a migration?

I need to remove a table with an old schema from it, not sure how to do this

I tried forcing a previous version on `config.schemaMigration` to write a custom one-time migration block to solve the issue, but Realm complains at start. Is there a way to force Realm opening the database anyway so I solve the migration?

Comment: You'd have to provide a configuration to the `Realm.getInstance()` method which specifies a version and a migration, and the version has to be higher than the current one.

Answer (score 0):

The safest is definitely to bump the schema version and fix the problem in the new version. Doing it any other way has a chance of breaking your users app.

However, If you want, you can use our Dynamic API to open a Realm without triggering a migration and make your changes there: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#dynamic-realms

Then removing any class is done the following way:

```
DynamicRealm realm = DynamicRealm.getInstance(config);
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.getSchema().remove("TableName");
realm.commitTransaction();
realm.close();
```

Comment: Thanks! is there an equivalent for Swift?

Comment: in Swift, you could perform a migration with the class removed from your schema, and calling [`Migration.deleteData(_:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Migration.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift9Migration10deleteDataFSSSb) to fully clean up that class from the file. You could then use [`Realm.writeCopyToPath(_:encryptionKey:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm15writeCopyToPathFzTSS13encryptionKeyGSqCSo6NSData__T_), which would write a new Realm file with a schema version of `0`. Then set whatever schema version you want for the new file.